# Generating many keys: how many CSPRNGs to use?

Tags: cryptography, random, key-generation

Say I want to create many random AES keys and have access to a secure source of random numbers `SecRand`.

I see two extremes of how I could write a key factory.

Use the same random source for all keys:

```
KeyFactoryA {
    private r = new SecRand()

    makeKey() {
        // create a key using r
    }
}
```

Use a new source for every key:

```
KeyFactoryB {
    makeKey() {
        r = new SecRand()
        // create a key using r
    }
}
```

I remember from statistics lectures (different field, I know) that the aggregate stream of random bits used in `B` would not necessarily be uniformly random; that is, `B` would be statistically weak. Also, it requires a larger pool of entropy to initialize all the different `r`.

`A`, on the other hand, may create many keys from a small initial pool of entropy. That does not sound too good either.

Are there any security-related differences between the two options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**What you want for your key(s) is to be completely unpredictable.**

There are now three cases to distinguish which really depend on your "secure random" class / object.

1. **It starts with high entropy and then drops.** If your source of entropy is really good, this shouldn't happen, but if it does you may either use a new instance (like you did in B) or you instantiate what cryptographers call a *pseudo-random generator* (PRG, ie a *strong* stream cipher encrypting zeroes) using your high-entropy input and use the resulding key stream as continuous source of computationally unpredictable key material. Note that if you use the output directly that the output *must be **uniformly** random* which means that if you use a direct physical effect or some gaussian-sampling RNG, you *really* should *securely* hash the output of the RNG and then feed it into a PRG which will remove all potential bias.
2. **It starts off badly and then increases in entropy over time.** In this case you want to take the entropy you gain over time and *condense* it into a short-highly unpredictable string using a *secure* hash function and use that to instantiate a PRG.
3. **It's always a good source of *uniformly* random numbers.** In this case it doesn't really matter which approach you follow, eg using only instance forever, spawning many new instances or using a PRG, all of them should be fine.

Comment: Thanks! I'm looking at Apple's CommonCrypt (the [recommended DRBG of which](https://github.com/Apple-FOSS-Mirror/CommonCrypto/blob/master/Source/CommonCryptoSPI/CommonRandomSPI.h) does what you propose in 1 afaict) and Java's SecureRandom (the same?). So if I use those as primitives, from my perspective I'm in case 3. Did I get that correctly?

Comment: @Raphael yep, those two claim to be CSPRNGs and thus you're indeed in case 3 :)

Comment: Phew, that's a relief: smart people have done all the thinking for me! What a luxury. :D